# Error in Maven execution with Java version 16.0.1

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I upgraded my Java version from 1.8 to 16.0.1 and accordingly updated Maven to 3.8.1.

Upon executing the test suites through Maven commands (`mvn verify`), I am getting errors as below:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @40f9161a
```

The execution works perfectly fine if I am doing execution through Eclipse.

Any ideas on what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading it is a good practice to upgrade one version at a time. You will usually get a deprecation warning before something actually breaks.

[Warnings with gradle, cucumber and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51915980/warnings-with-gradle-cucumber-and-selenium)

So consider upgrading your version of Cucumber before upgrading your Java version.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/release-notes

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did in-fact redo the upgrade but more on step by step process and the same worked.